# uuidtools, rspec and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, uuid

I'm working with the UUIDTools gem in Rails 3 and running into some problems.  It seems to work fine in practice:

```
> item = Item.create
 => #<Item uuid: "e9d00043-9200-4497-a55c-509c5de3dd88", created_at: "2012-01-09 01:56:49", updated_at: "2012-01-09 01:56:49">
> item.id
 => "e9d00043-9200-4497-a55c-509c5de3dd88"
```

But then in my specs it tells a different story:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Item do
  it 'should assign an id' do
    item = Item.create
    puts "item id: #{item.id}"
  end
end
```

Running this spec shows:

```
item id: 5
.

Finished in 2.21 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

Where's my guid?  There doesn't seem to be any pattern to what id is assigned, I've run this a bunch of times and seen it go anywhere from 0 to up in the thousands.

Here is my migration:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items, :id => false do |t|
      t.string :uuid, :null => false, :primary => true

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :items, :uuid, :unique => true
  end
end
```

My model:

```
require 'uuid_helper'

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UUIDHelper
end
```

And my uuid_helper:

```
module UUIDHelper
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      set_primary_key :uuid
      attr_readonly :uuid
      before_create :set_uuid

      private

      def set_uuid
        self.uuid = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Putting some debugger logic into `set_uuid` I've discovered that it's doing `to_i` on the uuid at some point.  Any suggestions?

**Update** This seems to be a bug in the Rails test environment.  When I run `RAILS_ENV=test rails console` I get the same behavior as in the specs--the guids are chopped off.

Comment: Hmm, looking at this some more I discovered that the databases themselves were different.  I dropped the tables and reran the migrations and everything seems to be fine.  Could be I left my test database in a weird state modifying my migrations locally.

Comment: And more weirdness.  Some combination of migrating and creating databases seems to leave schema.rb in an inconsistent state.  I've tried dropping all tables, removing schema.rb and starting from scratch, but I still can't seem to get it back to working.

Comment: Okay, well it seems to have been a bug in rails.  I was using Rails 3.1.1 before and in playing around I upgraded to Rails 3.1.3.  That's when things worked out in my above comment.  When I reverted to 3.1.1 it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the answer was to upgrade to Rails 3.1.3 from 3.1.1.